# Reference a Function in Another File in Another Directory

Tags: symfony

I have a component in my Store bundle that needs to access a function `getCode()` in my Foundation bundle. I have tried referencing this file via `use \project\FondationBundle\Foundation\collection\GlobalCollection`. This did not work. Any suggestions?

The error reported:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function project\CmsBundle\Cms\Components\getCurrencyCode() in...`

It seems that Symfony is looking in the wrong directory.

EDIT - Fixed a typo. The proper path is `\project\FondationBundle\Foundation\collection\GlobalCollection`

Comment: Just to test, what if you call your function with `\project\FondationBundle\Cms\collection\GlobalCollection\getCode()`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I got the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function project\FoundationBundle\Cms\Collection\GlobalCollection\getCode() in...`

Comment: I am 100% sure I copied+pasted the path correctly.

Comment: And what does the namespace declaration look like where you have `getCode()`?

Comment: The namespace in GlobalCollection is project\FoundationBundle\Foundation\Collection

Comment: The namespace in the file where I am trying to call `getCode()` is project\CmsBundle\Cms\Components`. Will there be a problem as they are different namespaces?

Comment: What if you call `project\CmsBundle\Cms\Components\getCode()` then?

Comment: I received the error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function project\CmsBundle\Cms\Components\getCode() in...`

Comment: I want to note that `GlobalCollection` is the name of my PHP file that contains `getCode()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23176/discussion-between-cheesemacfly-and-icu222much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a customized solution only for my project. My co-worker wrote some code that I just ended up copying. Upon doing further research, the direction that cheesemacfly has directed me is correct, however, not possible to implement in my situation.